# Sending multiple selected items to Controller via AJAX

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a list of policies that I'm displaying to the end user. Each policy entry has a checkbox to indicate whether or not they want to select that policy. They can choose multiple policies. Once they click on the Next button I want to be able to send the policies back to my controller(with the updated checkbox values) via an AJAX call. I see many examples of sending data when it's just one item but I can't get it working for multiple. I feel like it's something easy but I'm struggling and I'm hoping someone can help. Here's what I have thus far.

**ViewModel:**

```
public class PolicySelection
{
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
    public string PolicyType { get; set; }
    public string PolicyNumber { get; set; }
    public string Mod { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}

public class PolicySelectionViewModel
{
    public List<PolicySelection> Policies { get; set; }
}
```

**View:**

```
@model Models.PolicySelectionViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @{ string policyType = "";}
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Policies.Count; i++)
        {       
            if (Model.Policies[i].PolicyType != policyType)
            {
                <h3>@Model.Policies[i].PolicyType</h3>
                policyType = Model.Policies[i].PolicyType;
            }

            <div class="col-lg-1" style="width:5%;">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Policies[i].Selected)
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 padding-0">
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Policies[i].PolicyNumber)<text>-</text>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Policies[i].Mod)
            </div>

            <div>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Policies[i].CompanyName)
            </div>
        }
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-default btn-primary" style="position:absolute; left:300px; bottom:7px; width: 200px;" onclick="Next()" type="button">Next</button>
</div>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetModelData()
    {
        return $("form").serializeArray();
    }

    function Next()
    {
        var url = '@Url.Action("VerifyPolicies", "Home")';
        var model = GetModelData();
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: { PolicyList: model},
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public string VerifyPolicies(PolicySelectionViewModel PolicyList)
{
    string selectedPolicyNumbers = string.Empty;

    foreach(var policy in PolicyList.Policies)
    {
        if(policy.Selected)
        {
            selectedPolicyNumbers += policy.PolicyNumber + ',';
        }
    }
    return selectedPolicyNumber;
}
```

I ran this with 3 policies and checked the checkbox for 2 of them. When I break in my controller the PolicyList object had 5 policies and each policy's field is null except for Selected which is always false. I tried again this time just checking one of the 3 policies and now the PolicyList object had 4 objects. Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Comment: `$("form").serialize();` - not `serialieArray()` and its just `data: model,`. But all your posting back is is values for checkboxes, which by itself is a bit useless - you would at least to include a form control for something the identifies the Policy

Comment: I tried your suggestion and the PolicyList object in the controller is null. As for your second comment, what I'm trying to do is send all of the Model object back to the controller, not just the values for the checkbox. Realistically what I need is the PolicyNumber, Mod and Selected values.

Comment: Impossible unless there is other code you have not shown that is causing the issue. But all you have generated is a form control for the `Selected` - all the other properties are just `DisplayFor()` which does not generate a form control

Comment: My apologies, it turns out you were right. I was leaving the {} around model which didn't work. I then added a HiddenFor for each Property I wanted returned with the Model and that worked. If you want to type up a quick answer I can accept it or I'll do it if you don't. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Its late here and I'm about to sign off, so feel free to add your own answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Stephen Muecke I was able to get it working. I had to remove the curly braces {} and the property name(PolicyList) from the data option in the Ajax call, add Hidden Fields for the other properties I wanted to pass back and use .serialize() instead of .serializeArray(). Here's what my working View looks like:

**View:**

```
@model Models.PolicySelectionViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @{ string policyType = "";}
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Policies.Count; i++)
        {       
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Policies[i].PolicyNumber);
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Policies[i].Mod);
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Policies[i].PolicyType);

            if (Model.Policies[i].PolicyType != policyType)
            {
                <h3>@Model.Policies[i].PolicyType</h3>
                policyType = Model.Policies[i].PolicyType;
            }

            <div class="col-lg-1" style="width:5%;">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Policies[i].Selected)
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 padding-0">
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Policies[i].PolicyNumber)<text>-</text>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Policies[i].Mod)
            </div>

            <div>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Policies[i].CompanyName)
            </div>
        }
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-default btn-primary" style="position:absolute; left:300px; bottom:7px; width: 200px;" onclick="Next()" type="button">Next</button>
</div>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetModelData()
    {
        return $("form").serialize();
    }

    function Next()
    {
        var url = '@Url.Action("VerifyPolicies", "Home")';
        var model = GetModelData();
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: model,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

My Controller and ViewModel stayed the same. Thanks again to Stephen for his help with this.